# How to get the number of hours logged by an individual in jira for a particular day (in python)

Tags: python, report, jira

I am writing python module and in that i need to generate a report and for that, i need to know how many hours were logged by an individual in jira for a particular day. I tried to search a lot but didnt get any proper solution.

Im using the atlassian-python-api

Assume, i have the user and his token

even a query would be fine. I can use jira.jql() if the query is able to return proper results

Comment: Do you need on how to do it or do you need what package ?

Comment: This may help https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/REST-API-to-fetch-the-logged-hours-for-particular-project/qaq-p/1272760

Comment: I dont want hours logged for a particular project. I want hours logged by a particular person (lets say myself) on a particular day

@abdul, Im currently ugin atlassian-python-api, if you know any other module which has this capability, i can adopt that.